# Where better to keep common functions?

Tags: nestjs

I have functions for working with date in class.

```
export class DateName {
  weekDaysList() {...}
}
```

Do I need to create a module with a service for a date?
Import the class where needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experience, a service should contain methods that communicate between the controllers and the persistent layers.

Date functions, in this case, should live in the helper or utility folder.